# Regex to match alphanumeric and spaces

Tags: c#, regex

What am I doing wrong here?

```
string q = "john s!";
string clean = Regex.Replace(q, @"([^a-zA-Z0-9]|^\s)", string.Empty);
// clean == "johns". I want "john s";
```

Comment: ok, duh i'm dumb ^ is starts with...i'm tired. still don't know how to match just a space

Answer (score 78, accepted):

just a FYI

```
string clean = Regex.Replace(q, @"[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]", string.Empty);
```

would actually be better like

```
string clean = Regex.Replace(q, @"[^\w\s]", string.Empty);
```

Comment: "\w" is not the same as "a-zA-Z0-9". "\w" includes chars outside that range

Comment: Note that `\s` matches much more than just spaces, it matches any whitespace character. [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/character-classes-in-regular-expressions#whitespace-character-s)

Answer (score 23):

This:

```
string clean = Regex.Replace(dirty, "[^a-zA-Z0-9\x20]", String.Empty);
```

> > **\x20** is ascii hex for 'space' character

you can add more individual characters that you want to be allowed.
If you want for example **"?"** to be ok in the return string add **\x3f**.

Comment: you can also match an **ASCII** character as octal. In that case **\040** represents a space character.

Comment: ...or you could just type them verbatim if they are simple things like space or ?:
`[^A-Za-z0-9 ?]` etc.

Answer (score 15):

I got it:

```
string clean = Regex.Replace(q, @"[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]", string.Empty);
```

Didn't know you could put \s in the brackets

Comment: Your regex will only match strings which do not contain alpha numerics, numbers or spaces.  The ^ at the start of a [] means "not anything inside here"

Comment: That's exactly what I want. In the Regex.Replace, I want to match anything that's NOT a letter, number or space.

Answer (score 5):

The following regex is for space inclusion in textbox.

```
Regex r = new Regex("^[a-zA-Z\\s]+");
r.IsMatch(textbox1.text);
```

This works fine for me.

Comment: Wouldn't `[A-z\\s]` be easier than `[a-zA-Z\\s]`?

Comment: @Alexander (though at this point in time, it more for any later viewers of this comment) - there are non alphabetic characters between "Z" and "a" that your regex would match but vivek's does not.

Answer (score 4):

I suspect ^ doesn't work the way you think it does outside of a character class.

What you're telling it to do is replace everything that isn't an alphanumeric with an empty string, OR any leading space.  I think what you mean to say is that spaces are ok to not replace - try moving the \s into the [] class.

Comment: you're right, that's starts with (which i knew, but it's late)

Answer (score 2):

There appear to be two problems.

1. You're using the ^ outside a [] which matches the start of the line
2. You're not using a * or + which means you will only match a single character.

I think you want the following regex @"([^a-zA-Z0-9\s])+"

Comment: Wouldn't that replace all the alphanumerics and spaces with the empty string?

Comment: Regarding #2, the quantifier doesn't really matter as he wants to replace all non-matching characters in the string rather than just a single run of them, which requires a global replace (.../g in Perl, not sure of the C# syntax), with or without the */+.

Comment: c# regex is @"^[a-zA-Z0-9\r]+$"

Answer (score 1):

bottom regex with space, supports all keyboard letters from different culture

```
 string input = "78-selim güzel667.,?";
 Regex regex = new Regex(@"[^\w\x20]|[\d]");
 var result= regex.Replace(input,"");
 //selim güzel
```

Answer (score 0):

The circumflex inside the square brackets means all characters except the subsequent range.  You want a circumflex outside of square brackets.

Comment: Yeah, I want it inside. Match anything that isn't these character ranges

Comment: Oh, where you said "I want" I thought you meant you wanted a regular expression to match that.  You meant you want the result of Replace to be that.  So you want the regular expression to not match that.  My brain hurts.

Answer (score 0):

This regex will help you to filter if there is at least one alphanumeric character and zero or more special characters i.e. _ (underscore), \s whitespace, -(hyphen)

```
string comparer = "string you want to compare";
Regex r = new Regex(@"^([a-zA-Z0-9]+[_\s-]*)+$");

if (!r.IsMatch(comparer))
{
   return false;
}    
return true;
```

Create a set using `[a-zA-Z0-9]+` for alphanumeric characters, "+" sign (a quantifier) at the end of the set will make sure that there will be at least one alphanumeric character within the `comparer`.

Create another set `[_\s-]*` for special characters, "*" quantifier is to validate that there can be special characters within `comparer` string.

Pack these sets into a capture group `([a-zA-Z0-9]+[_\s-]*)+` to say that the `comparer` string should occupy these features.

Answer (score 0):

```
[RegularExpression(@"^[A-Z]+[a-zA-Z""'\s-]*$")]
```

Above syntax also accepts space

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).