# Replacing alpha characters and spaces in string with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace

I have a string that allows only numbers

```
$(this).val($(this).val().replace(/([a-zA-Z])/g, ""));
```

How can I add a space, so this will get replaced with "" same way in one string?

Comment: try this... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/181356/regex-to-match-alphanumeric-and-spaces

Comment: where do you want to add space exactly?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to allow only numeric (0-9) in HTML  inputbox using jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/995183/how-to-allow-only-numeric-0-9-in-html-inputbox-using-jquery)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To match only non-numerics, you would do `[^0-9]` instead of `[a-zA-Z]` (this is called a [negated character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated)).

If you want an input to allow only numbers, with HTML5 you can simply do `<input type="number">`. For wider support, there are plenty of JavaScript solutions, have a look at [How to allow only numeric (0-9) in HTML  inputbox using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/995183) as suggested in the comments.

Comment: Your link works fine if the user types the text but it fails if the user pastes the text.

Comment: @schlingel There are plenty of different solutions at that link, but it does indeed seem like they are all using different key-events instead of the `input` event. I edited your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7rSVb/3/

Answer (score 3):

Just add the space to your Regex:

```
  "asfasd asdf asdf".replace(/([a-zA-Z ])/g, "");
```

Yields:

```
  ""
```

Edit:
I misunderstood your question. If you want to prevent every input but numbers use this regex:

```
function removeNotAllowedChars($input) {
   $input.val($input.val().replace(/[^0-9]/g, ''));
}

$('#myText')
   .keyup(function() {
     var $input = $(this);
     removeNotAllowedChars($input);
   })
   .change(function() {
     var $input = $(this);
     removeNotAllowedChars($input);
   });
```

Using these script removes the input instantly if the user types the character and if he pastes the input after the focus changes. Try it here: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7rSVb/1)

Comment: That's great, thank you,  but just thinking that would be easier to prevent the space key in general. This is my function $('*[data-type-validation="numeric"]).each(function (index, value) {
            $(this).change(function () {
                $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/([a-zA-Z ])/g, ""));
                 
            })
        }); any idea please?

Answer (score 0):

use `\s` - Matches a single white space character, including space, tab, form feed, line feed. Equivalent to

[Regex Guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)